# How to share an entity that is managed by the host but is accessible by tenants?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

Using aspnetboilerplate v3.6

The application has an entity `Book` that is managed(CRUD) by the Host only. However, tenants should have Read Only access to this entity.

For example, a tenant user should be able to see the list of books available. The goal is to have a tenant user to select a list of their favorite books, but these books are only created by the host.

Comment: you can use add permission for this and use `[AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.XYZ_ReadOnly)]` with the method.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Book: Entity, IMayHaveTenant
{
    public int? TenantId { get; set; }

    public string BookName { get; set; }
}
```

The IMayHaveTenant interface defines TenantId but it's nullable.
A null value means this is a host entity, a non-null value means this entity is owned by a tenant in which the Id is the TenantId. ASP.NET Boilerplate uses the IAbpSession to get the current TenantId by default. The IMayHaveTenant filter is not as common as IMustHaveTenant, but you may need it for common entitiy types used by both the host and tenants.

When you want to get all Books from tenants page.

```
using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))
{
    var allBooks = _bookRepository.GetAllList();                
}
```

---

Or you can just throw IMayHaveTenant and try

```
public class Book: Entity
{
    public string BookName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Alpers' answer....

If you have that particular entity behind a feature using the `[RequiresFeature]` AppService attribute. Make sure you've configured the Main module to `IgnoreFeatureCheckForHostUsers` if you want to manage that entity in the host site. ;)

```
Configuration.MultiTenancy.IgnoreFeatureCheckForHostUsers = true;
```

[Source: Ignore the RequiresFeature for host user](https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions/8332)

This one bit me....